# assign string arrays to list<myclass>

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have faced an Stackoverflow when I run this code

```
class Students
{
    public int SID { get { return SID; } set { SID = value; } }
    public string SName { get { return SName; } set { SName = value; } }      
}
```

The problem is located in foreach(string s in names).. I could not store the string array into my datastructure
thanks in advance

```
 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         List<Students> sList = new List<Students>();           
         string[] names = new string[5]  {"Matt", "Joanne", "Robert"};
         System.Console.WriteLine("{0} words in text:", names.Length);

         foreach (string s in names)
         {
             Students st = new Students();
             st.SName = s;
             sList.Add(st);
             System.Console.WriteLine("test{0}",s);
         }

         foreach (Students sn in sList) Console.WriteLine(sn);

         Console.ReadLine();
     }
 }
```

Comment: are you facing a null reference exception

Answer (score 6):

```
public int SID 
{ 
  get 
  { 
     //here you try to return SID, again the "get" method is called
     //hence the StackOverflowException
      return SID; 
  }
  set 
  { 
     //same issue here
      SID = value; 
  } 
}
```

change your code to:

```
public int SID { get; set; }
```

or use a field:

```
private int _SID;
public int SID 
{ 
  get 
  { 
     return _SID; 
  }
  set 
  { 
     _SID = value; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int SID { get { return SID; } set { SID = value; } }
```

Think for a moment what is happening there?
Think for a moment what is happening there?
Think for a moment what is happening there?
Think for a moment what is happening there?
Think for a moment what is happening there?
Think for a moment what is happening there?
Think for a moment what is happening there?
Think for a moment what is happening there?
Think for a moment what is happening there?

Comment: Search the keyword *recursion* on google, and you will be told "Do you mean *recursion*?" :D

Answer (score 0):

The SID property is not the problem since it is never called by your code.  The SName property is the one causing the stack overflow.  Change it to

> `public string SName { get; set; }`

so it does not reference itself.

`names` is declared as `string[5]` but only initialized with 3 names.  Change that to `string[3]` or add two more names.

You will also find that `Console.WriteLine(sn);` outputs the same class name **AppName.Students** for every student instead of useful student info.  That is fixed by adding something like this to your Student class

> `public override string ToString() { return SID + " " + SName; }`

This overrides the default ToString method that is part of every .NET object and displays whatever you specify instead.  For this example to work you'll also want to update the SID property to `public string SID { get; set; }` to avoid more stack overflows.